# (crl + /) in vscode short cut makes incorrect jsx comment

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

In vscode in  react class component (crl + /) will create the correct comment for JSX

```
{/* comment */}
```

But in vscode in  react functional component (crl + /) will create an incorrect comment for JSX

```
// comment
```

How do you fix this in vscode

[image]

Comment: Isn't this more of a bug report to the authors of the VSCode extension that does this than a generally useful question for SO?

Comment: What language is it set to

Comment: Could you try `ctrl + k, ctrl + u` first ctrl + k then ctrl + u.

Comment: Did it work @Hello-World ? Because I tried in my VSCode and `ctrl + /` actually works in react functional component. But still, there are alternative so gave you the above shortcuts.

Comment: Language : Javascript react  and Babel Javasctipt.
Non of the short cuts above worked.

Have you installed another extension?

Comment: Sorry but I think it might be due to extension since it didn't work in yours. I am unable to identify the extension.

Comment: Uninstall the Babel extension. It is not maintained and will give you a worse experience working with JavaScript in VS Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent few hours on this problem, and the easiest solution I found is the following:
Yes the problem is coming with the installation of Babel ES6/ES7 extension as many noticed,
and when you uninstall or deactivate it, VScode retrieves it's normal behaviour:
Ctrl + / => Toggle Line Comment for line or block selected with `//` for JS, JSX, ... files;
Shift + Alt + A => Toggle Block Comment for line or block selected between `<!--` `-->`  in HTML files, between `/*` `*/` in JS expressions and between `{/*` `*/}` in JSX files for markup tags in render/return...
So if you want to keep Babel ES6/ES7 extension active and still have such a behaviour:
You can parameter your own shortcut key-binding combination in the file keybindings.json
( File/Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts (or Ctrl+K+S) and then click the little file icon on top right
for selecting Open Keyboard Shortcuts wich opens keybindings.json)
where you use the VScode build-in command "editor.action.insertSnippet" as following:

```
[
    {
    "key": "shift+alt+a",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "{/*\n ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} \n*/}$0"
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == 'javascript' && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

Place the `/n` where you want in the expression for breaking lines, and the `$0` for final placement(s) of cursor.
Then save, and it's working straight :) only in JS and JSX files
If you want to specify another language just replace `'javascript'` in the `"when"` expression
by the one you want from this VScode Language Identifiers list :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers
And of course if you want another snippet behaviour : just replace the `{/*` by what you want in the `"args"` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the asker's comments, this is caused a the Babel extension.

You do not need any extensions to work with react in VS Code. [This Babel extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring) specifically was last updated in 2016 and can break many basic language features such as highlighting and commenting